# Get the value from the XML SQL Select Statement

Tags: sql-server, openxml

I am being trying to understand and learn how to take value from XML. I have taken a reference of an XML document from the link below.

[Link](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24787037/What-is-wrong-with-this-XML-File.html)

In order to get clarification I have removed some of the unwanted xml parts.

Example

```
 <?Label VCAT|RESERVATION|21405|SUCCESS?> 
<Reservation xmlns="reservation.fidelio.4.0" mfShareAction="NA" mfReservationAction="EDIT">
    <reservationID>11650</reservationID>
        <GuestCounts>
            <GuestCount>
                <ageQualifyingCode>ADULT</ageQualifyingCode> 
                <mfCount>1</mfCount> 
            </GuestCount>
            <GuestCount>
                <ageQualifyingCode>CHILD</ageQualifyingCode> 
                <mfCount>0</mfCount> 
            </GuestCount>
        </GuestCounts>
</Reservation>
```

In HTML, For Example google.com - To target input for that Page we use XPath as `//input[@name='q']`. Similarly inorder to target a node we can specify `//ageQualifyingCode` to get value within that node. So based on that I have created a query specified below. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this query as I am getting output as NULL.

```
   DECLARE @XmlDocumentHandle int 
DECLARE @XMLData XML
SET @XMLData ='<?Label VCAT|RESERVATION|21405|SUCCESS?> 
<Reservation xmlns="reservation.fidelio.4.0" mfShareAction="NA" mfReservationAction="EDIT">
    <reservationID>11650</reservationID>
        <GuestCounts>
            <GuestCount>
                <ageQualifyingCode>ADULT</ageQualifyingCode> 
                <mfCount>1</mfCount> 
            </GuestCount>
            <GuestCount>
                <ageQualifyingCode>CHILD</ageQualifyingCode> 
                <mfCount>0</mfCount> 
            </GuestCount>
        </GuestCounts>
</Reservation>'
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @XmlDocumentHandle OUTPUT, @XMLData  

SELECT *  
FROM OPENXML (@XmlDocumentHandle, '/Reservation/GuestCounts/GuestCount/',2)  
WITH (ageQualifyingCode     varchar(10)   '//ageQualifyingCode',  
      mfCount  int '//mfCount')  
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @XmlDocumentHandle
```

I have also tried using XQuery mentioned below but no result

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT TOP 1  
X.Y.value('(ageQualifyingCode)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS ageQualifyingCode, X.Y.value('(mfCount)[1]', 'int') AS mfCount
FROM #temp1 t
CROSS APPLY t.xmlBody.nodes('Reservation/GuestCounts/GuestCount') AS X(Y)
) T
```

Also, how will I be able to target reservationID in same cross apply?

Output

```
+---------------+-------------------+---------+
| reservationID | ageQualifyingCode | mfCount |
+---------------+-------------------+---------+
| 11650         | ADULT             | 1       |
+---------------+-------------------+---------+
| 11650         | CHILD             | 0       |
+---------------+-------------------+---------+
```

Comment: That is an incredibly *old* way of reading XML in SQL Server. [XQUERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-language-reference-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) has been supported since at least SQL Server 2008, probably even 2005 or earlier.

Comment: @Larnu Ok then which way would you create the SQL query using XQuery based on the example I have provided

Comment: So, for the above, what is the expected output you're after? Could you show that in your question please?

Comment: @Larnu As per your request I have added my output as well as modified my question little bit too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the XQuery approach - define the XML namespace, and then query into the XML:

```
DECLARE @XMLData XML
SET @XMLData ='<?Label VCAT|RESERVATION|21405|SUCCESS?> 
<Reservation xmlns="reservation.fidelio.4.0" mfShareAction="NA" mfReservationAction="EDIT">
    <reservationID>11650</reservationID>
    <HotelReference>
        <GuestCounts>
            <GuestCount>
                <ageQualifyingCode>ADULT</ageQualifyingCode> 
                <mfCount>1</mfCount> 
            </GuestCount>
            <GuestCount>
                <ageQualifyingCode>CHILD</ageQualifyingCode> 
                <mfCount>0</mfCount> 
            </GuestCount>
        </GuestCounts>
    </HotelReference>
</Reservation>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'reservation.fidelio.4.0')
SELECT
    ReservationId = @XmlData.value('(/Reservation/reservationID)[1]', 'int'),
    AgeQualifyingCode = xc.value('(ageQualifyingCode)[1]', 'varchar(20)'),
    MfCount = xc.value('(mfCount)[1]', 'int')
FROM
    @XMLData.nodes('/Reservation/HotelReference/GuestCounts/GuestCount') AS XT(XC)
```

This will return the two rows with the values for `<ageQualifyingCode>` and `<mfCount>`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One question which I have added. Based on that will I me able to target another node such as reservationID in query? Not even just one node but multiple node outside GuestCounts?

Comment: Also what does XT(XC) means? Can we give any alias name?

Comment: @user1413: sure you can - updated my response to show this.

Comment: @user1413: the `.nodes()` call in XQuery returns a "virtual" table with one entry for each XML node that matches the XPath expression. In SQL Server, you have to give that "virtual" table and the single column inside it **aliases**. I typically pick `XT` for the "XML table`, and `XC` for the XML column - but you can name those anything you want - you just have to provide something (which you can then use to grab the values in a `.value()` call)

Comment: Thank you for your explaination.

Comment: Will you be able to help me out in my new post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60726815/how-can-i-extract-multiple-xml-node-values-in-single-execution